# Windows 8 XAML possible bug - using images causes text controls to disappear

Tags: xaml, winrt-xaml, windows-8.1, winrt-component

I have a strange problem happening intermittently with my apps where textbox controls would disappear intermittently. I have narrowed the cause of this down to having image files (small logos etc) on my page.

I have managed to create a simple project which contains an xaml page with an image and 2 textblocks (these are in grids).
I have found on two test tablets that I can re-create the problem by going to task manager and creating a dump file for the running app.

After I do this twice and resume the app, the two textblocks disappear.

This exact problem is happening intermittently in my live apps.

Has anyone any ideas why this might be happening or what I should try next? I have no idea why creating a dump file forces the issue.

You can see a video of me re-creating the issue here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DF2BE823348DEA6C!74381&authkey=!AIvSU05r0363S3Y&ithint=video%2cMOV

The test project in the video can be downloaded from here:

https://onedrive.live.com/redir?resid=DF2BE823348DEA6C!74382&authkey=!AIGHSdezFcCbEZQ&ithint=file%2czip

So far I can re-create it with the exact same steps on my two different tablets - both running Windows 8.1 Pro 32bit.

If you are familiar with sideloading apps and you have a 64bit tablet I would be really appreciative if someone was able to test out the exact same steps as seen in the video.

Any help would be extremely appreciated as I am clueless as to where to go next.

Answer (score 1):

I finally got to the bottom of this. The problem was down to the intel graphics driver that was installed on the tablets.

An updated driver was released around April which seemed to resolve the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I have observed this problem of disappearing controls on views that do not contain image files but rather a background image. After reading your method of how to reproduce the issue, I've since removed the background image and replaced with a LinearGradientBrush and retested with the dump file process. The problem seems to have disappeared. (I'm running 32-bit as well.)